# WPF XAML Local (child) styles are being overwritten. Why?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dialog, wpf-controls

I wrote a simple dialog (XAML/WPF) and a test app and the dialog looks fine. In particular the buttons in the ListView have rounded corners. I've posted a picture and the code below.
The problem? When I use this dialog inside a much larger program (codebase too large to share), **the rounded corners** and other styling is gone.  I strongly suspect something in the larger program is taking precedence over my local work.  Perhaps a global style for buttons or some such thing?

1. I'd like to understand what is going on. Presumably something in the main app takes precedence over my xaml work?
2. I'd like to know if there is a way to say "don't inherit styles from the app itself. Rather use WPF defaults unless I override them.", assuming that is the problem.

See picture (notice rounded corners)

[image]

See picture from when I call it from actual main application instead of test application

Notice in particular lack of rounded corners. My work to produce rounded corners is gone! Also, in the test app, hovering over a button shows a blue color which I assume is default (I didn't do it). When called from main app, no such hover effect. I suspect the main app gets rid of that somewhere.

[image]

Here's the simple dialog xaml

```
<Window x:Class="FirmsDialog"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dialogs"
                
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="400"
        Width="390" Height="720" BorderBrush="LightGray"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize"
         x:Name="FirmsViewDlg" Loaded="FirmsViewDlg_Loaded"
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <FontFamily x:Key="AvenirNextforCompany">
            pack://application:,,,/Assets/Fonts/#AvenirNextforCompany
        </FontFamily>
        <local:ReverseObjectToBool x:Key="ReverseObjectToBoolConverter" />

        <local:ObjectToBool x:Key="ObjectToBoolConverter" />
       
        
        

        
        <!-- New style -->
        <Style x:Key="StyleListViewItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            
        </Style>

        <!-- Existing style -->
        <Style x:Key="StyleListView" TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource StyleListViewItem}"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <!-- ... -->
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Select Company" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20px" Foreground="#393a3d" FontFamily="{StaticResource AvenirNextforCompany}" FontWeight="Normal"  ></Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Accountant companies" Margin="10,0" FontFamily="{StaticResource AvenirNextforCompany}" FontSize="14px" Foreground="#8d9096" FontWeight="Normal"></Label>
        <ListView  BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding RealmMembershipInfo}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFirm}"   x:Name="realmListBox" 
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Background="White"              
                   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                    BorderBrush="LightGray">
            
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button  Click="Button_Click" 
                       
                         MinHeight="65" Padding="10,0,10,0"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     BorderBrush="LightGray"    Background="White" Foreground="#393a3d"  FontFamily="{StaticResource AvenirNextforCompany}" FontSize="14px" FontWeight="SemiBold"
                            
                        >
                        <Button.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="9"/>


                            </Style>

                        </Button.Resources>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding displayName}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Foreground="#393a3d"  FontFamily="{StaticResource AvenirNextforCompany}" FontSize="14px" FontWeight="Bold" >

                        </TextBlock>

                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,10,10"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Simple program to show the Xaml above

```
using Dialogs;
using Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestApp
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Button_SelectFirm(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         // hack code to set up dialog
         RealmMembershipInfo realmInfo = new RealmMembershipInfo();
         realmInfo.realmMembershipInfo = new List<RealmMembershipItem>();

         RealmMembershipItem item = new RealmMembershipItem();
         item.displayName = "Company 1";        
         realmInfo.realmMembershipInfo.Add(item);

         item = new RealmMembershipItem();
         item.displayName = "Company2";         
         realmInfo.realmMembershipInfo.Add(item);

         

         FirmsDialog dlg = new FirmsDialog(realmInfo);
         dlg.ShowDialog();
         MessageBox.Show("Your picked firm: " + dlg.SelectedFirm);
         
      }

      private void Button_SelectClient(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can inspect element and see which style has been used during debug in VS in Live visual tree.

Comment: Do you see a declaration for global style under App.xaml of the main app?

Comment: Note that the problem seems to be with the Button itself. No rounded corners and no blue color when you hover over it.  That is the Button.Resources section is not being honored in the full program BUT is being honored in the small test app.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the style on the Listview.

```
<ListView Style={StaticResource StyleListView} ....
```

And you are using the default style for the ItemsContainer. You need to add the a base style.

```
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn={StaticResource StyleListViewItem}...
```

Comment: Thanks for looking. How do I just revert to the WPF default base style?
And notice that button does have some resources associated with it (rounded corner) AND that rounded corner is shown perfectly when using the simple demo app.